# Print attachment image in data view web part

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt

I want include the attachment image directly in data view web part.

I used the below code snippet, it is displayed image name link, but I need to print image here.

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
    <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="ItemId"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

I tried up to my level but it's not getting displayed.

Comment: I think you need to improve your question to understand

Comment: Is this a FIS?  Can't you just have a link to document and then have the user print at thier own discretion?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to display the image?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the value of what you have already in your question to a variable. Then if the length of that variable is greater than zero you can display whatever image you choose.

Comment: Marc can you elaborate this solution you posted?
I would like to show the attachmenets as images.
THanks